# NodeJS Passport redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to implement user redirection with Passport on NodeJS and Express Backend script. The issue that I am facing is that my login page is not my default home page but it's rather this:

```
localhost:3000/login
```

I've managed to make it so that if user is not registered, he cannot access other pages such as `/index` or `/dashboard` but something breaks when I try to access hard-coded urls such as:

If I enter `localhost:3000/` I can gain access to the default `index.html` page even if I'm not logged in. Just to clarify - `localhost:3000/index` == `localhost:3000`.

If I decide to manipulate the route like this: `localhost:3000/Example/pages/index.html` or `localhost:3000/Example/pages/dashboard.html` it would allow me to access the pages even if I am logged in.

My question is, how can I restrict users to manipulate the route to the default homepage and any other pages which have not been declared in the Node Backend?

My Node Routes Code:

```
app.get('/login',
        function(req, res){
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
        });

    app.get('/index', isLoggedIn,
        function(req, res){
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
        });


    app.post('/login',
        passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
        function(req, res) {
            res.redirect('/index');
        });

      app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/index');
    });
```

I've tried using this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
if (req.session.user == undefined) {  
      return res.render('/login', {  failureRedirect:'/login'  });
    }   
    else {
        next();
    }
});
```

but I receive an error: **No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.**  I don't want to use JADE or Handlebars or anything else as an engine, just static HTML.

How can I restrict the route manipulation without having to define the rest of my node pages as `app.get(/something, function(req,res){});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a passport middleware to check if the user is authenticated

```
isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }

  res.redirect('/login');
};
```

And then you can do this

```
app.get('/someroute', isAuthenticated, (req, res)=>{
    // do what you want
});
```

Comment: what if I just have `'/'` instead of` `'/someroute' ` or leave it empty? Would it still work for static files?

Comment: it does not matter what the route is, you can use whatever you want. The idea here is the middleware isAuthenticated.

Comment: Doesn't work Vanka. I can still access the default home page and manipulate the route..

Comment: So i assume you use express.static somewhere ? You can try to add a line above it like: app.use(isAuthenticated).

Comment: I am currently using   `app.all('*/*', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
    });` but when I access the route: `localhost:3000` it doesn't redirect. That is my main issue. If I use a route with a slash `/something` it redirects but not for the default localhost path.

Comment: Change your `app.all('*/*')` to `app.all('*')`

Comment: It still allows me to access the default index page `localhost:3000`. This is  tricky since, `localhost:3000/index` is the same page as `localhost:3000`